# Testng changing test names dynamically for a generic test method

Tags: testng

i have one test method which runs ten times based on a dataprovider .. I want to change the name of the test to a custom meaningful one each time it is executed ..how do i do this in testng

Answer (score 0):

Yes, test name can be changed to show it in report based on the data provided from data-provider.

Since `@Test` is considered a method, you can use `@BeforeMethod` with `alwaysRun=true` and pass your data returned from data provider along with Method object. In side it you can customize your method with whatever way you want.

**Sample code :** (assuming testData array has more than or equal to 7 indexes to return)

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setTestName(Method method, Object[] testData) {
        String testCaseName = testData[0] + "_MyTest_" + testData[1] + "_" + testData[3] + "_"
                + DateUtils.convertUnixToNormalDate(Long.parseLong(testData[4].toString()), "MM/dd/yyyy").replace(" ", "_")
                + "_to_" + DateUtils.convertUnixToNormalDate(Long.parseLong(testData[5].toString()), "MM/dd/yyyy").replace(" ", "_") + "_view_" + testData[7];
        System.out.println(method.getName() + testCaseName);
        testName.set(method.getName() + "_" + testCaseName);
    }
```

Here since while using data provider tests might run in multiple threads based on your parallel execution configuration. The `testName` variable should be `ThreadLocal`.

```
private ThreadLocal<String> testName = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

Let us know if it fix your problem.

Comment: what is this testName variable .. is this a TestNG provided one ? how setting it changes TestNG pattern . I am not sure on the TestName variable only in this above code example

Comment: Its just a variable. Not related to testNg. It does not change any pattern. We used reflection here to change method name. Just to make sure that it changes the test’s name before executing it, we kept it in @BeforeMethod

Comment: i understood that u are using reflection to get the method name but how come setting the threadlocal variable with a "tweaked name" will make tetsng to remodify the test name

Comment: i cannot understand the testname.set

Comment: i want to tweak it in such a way so that i can add the modified method name to the itestresult result object